# JQuery login form codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In the part of redirect why is that it not goes to the that page. What happened is that it gets the text in the `Home/`.

During a page redirect, it does not go to the page. Rather, it gets the text from `Home/`, and I received this error:

> Uncaught Type Error : Cannot read property location of null

Here is the `Controller` code:

```
public function loginacc()
{
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()){ exit('no valid req.'); }
    $FormRules = array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' =>'Email',
                    'rules'=>'required|valid_email|trim|xss_clean'
                )
        );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($FormRules);
    if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
    {
        $email = trim(strip_tags($this->input->post('email')));
        $pass=trim(strip_tags($this->input->post('password')));
        $users = $this->db->get_where('accounts',array("email"=>$email,"pass"=>$pass))->result();
        if(empty($users))
        {
            echo "failed";
        }
        else
        {
            redirect(base_url().'Home/');
        }
    }//form validation
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="error">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
    }
}
```

This is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("form.loginform").on('submit', function(form)
            {   
                form.preventDefault();
                $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>Hauth/loginacc', $('form.loginform').serialize(),function(data)
                {
                    $('#error').html(data);   
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my login form:

```
        <form action="" method="post" id="loginform" class="loginform" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="lemail" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password"  class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="lpass" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" class="error" id="error" style="color:black;"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" id="btnlogin">Sign In</button>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div>
        </form>
```

This is the homepage view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LinkedShop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.close();
        window.opener.location.reload();

</script>
</head>

<body>
    asdasdasdas
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught Type Error : Cannot read property location of null 
is caused by    window.close();window.opener.location.reload(); . Already fixed it. The problem now is that why is it not redirecting to the controller i want

Comment: Be clear about what you're trying to do and, more importantly, where you're getting the error you're trying to solve. Back end? Front end? Line of code?

Comment: in the console .. back end

Comment: What exactly not redirecting you?

Comment: `console` usually means the Javascript console. Do you mean that or do you mean the PHP code is failing? (Which would be considered 'the back end'.)

Comment: @u_mulder If there an account I want it to redirect to the Home controller, The Home controller contains the homepage view which contains the asdasdasdas. What happens is that in my login page it displays asdasdasdas.

Comment: @NathanielFord Im sorry. There no error in the backend. I dont see any errors aside from what i see in the console, or the problem is that it does not redirect

Comment: Have you tried debugging the javascript code and stepping through it to find the line where the error arises?

Comment: There's no error its just it doesnt redirect to a new page

Answer (score 0):

i think the entire problem here is that you can't simply redirect in php after an ajax post - try this instead

```
public function loginacc()
{
    $arrReturnData = array();

    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $FormRules = array(
                array(
                        'field' => 'email',
                        'label' =>'Email',
                        'rules'=>'required|valid_email|trim|xss_clean'
                    )
            );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($FormRules);
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $email = trim(strip_tags($this->input->post('email')));
            $pass=trim(strip_tags($this->input->post('password')));
            $users = $this->db->get_where('accounts',array("email"=>$email,"pass"=>$pass))->result();
            if(empty($users))
            {
                $arrReturnData['error'] = "failed";
            }
            else
            {
                $arrReturnData['success'] = base_url().'Home/';
            }
        }//form validation
        else
        {
            $arrReturnData['error'] = validation_errors();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $arrReturnData['error'] = "no valid request";
    }

    echo json_encode($arrReturnData);

}
```

and your jquery should look like that

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("form.loginform").on('submit', function(form)
    {   
        form.preventDefault();
        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>Hauth/loginacc', $('form.loginform').serialize(),function(data)
        {
            if (typeof data.success !== "undefined")
            {
                window.location.href = data.success;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#error').html(data.error);   
            }

        })
    });
});
```